Powershell if function calling another function
I have 2 functions when I call the second function from the first one, always returns true doesn't matter if the second function has false return:
function IsPodRunning($podName) {
  Write-Output "IsPodRunning $podName"
  return $false;
}

function WaitForPodStart($podName) {
  While ($true) {
    If (IsPodRunning -podName $podName) {
      Write-Output "WaitForPodStart IsPodRunning"
      Break
    }else {
      Write-Output "WaitForPodStart IsNotPodRunning"
    }
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
  }
}

The second function works as expected if I call directly but not through another function.
IsPodRunning -podName "podName1" Works as expected
WaitForPodStart -podName "podName1" doesn't call second function
After making a bunch of tests I found the issue could be the if statement of the first function, but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

How did you reach the conclusion that "WaitForPodStart -podName "podName1" doesn't call second function"? What specific observations have you made?

What of the kubectl command always returns something? The positive result or an error message? In that case your function IsPodRunning will never return $false

Why not just set a debug break point and step through?

There are few reasons for this PowerShell function conflict behavior to verify. Check below to resolve the issue.
To avoid issues with function return values, use Write-Host instead of Write-Output for printing outputs to the console. Write-Host writes directly to the console, whereas Write-Output sends output to the pipeline, which can be interpreted as part of a function's return value.
Reference SO for the relevant information on difference between them.
function IsPodRunning($podName) {
  Write-Host "IsPodRunning $podName"
  return $false;
}


Alternatively, you can also remove return statement from the PowerShell function and modify the code as shown below.
function IsPodRunning($podName) {
  Write-Host "IsPodRunning $podName"
  $false;
}

And also check if statement is properly given under the WaitForPodStart :
If ($(IsPodRunning -podName $podName))
After modifying it, try checking the pod running status as shown below and it worked as expected for me.

